# AVL Tree Insertion - Access Violation Reading Location (Unable to read memory)

Tags: c++, memory, insert, tree

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Here is the error I am getting at run-time: Unhandled exception at 0x000D87D6 in FinalProject.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000013.
When I try to insert the third word, it breaks here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEkEF.png

See where it says "Unable to read memory"? I can't figure out why.

**FinalProject.cpp**:

```
#include "FileReaderAscii.h"
#include "AVL.h"

int main()
{
    std::string FileName = "I.txt";

    FileReaderAscii F;
    AVL A;

    std::set<std::string> ISet = F.ReadFile(FileName);

    for (std::set<std::string>::iterator it = ISet.begin(); it != ISet.end(); it++) {
        A.root = A.insert(A.root, *it);
    }

    //3.    Display the top three levels of your AVL tree
    A.displayAVL(A.root, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

**AVL.cpp:**

```
#include "AVL.h"

int AVL::heightAVL(AVLNode *temp) {
    int iFinalHeight = 0;
    if (temp != NULL) {
        int lHeight = heightAVL(temp->left);
        int rHeight = heightAVL(temp->right);
        int topHeight = std::max(lHeight, rHeight);
        iFinalHeight = topHeight + 1;
    }
    return iFinalHeight;
}

int AVL::diffAVL(AVLNode *temp) {
    int lHeight = heightAVL(temp->left);
    int rHeight = heightAVL(temp->right);
    int iBalance = lHeight - rHeight;

    return iBalance;
}

AVL::AVLNode *AVL::rrRotation(AVLNode *parent) {
    AVLNode *temp;
    temp = parent->right;
    parent->right = temp->left;
    temp->left = parent;
    return temp;
}

AVL::AVLNode *AVL::llRotation(AVLNode *parent) {
    AVLNode *temp;
    temp = parent->left;
    parent->left = temp->right;
    temp->right = parent;
    return temp;
}

AVL::AVLNode *AVL::lrRotation(AVLNode *parent) {
    AVLNode *temp;
    temp = parent->left;
    parent->left = rrRotation(temp);
    return llRotation(parent);
}

AVL::AVLNode *AVL::rlRotation(AVLNode *parent) {
    AVLNode *temp;
    temp = parent->right;
    parent->right = llRotation(temp);
    return rrRotation(parent);
}

AVL::AVLNode *AVL::balance(AVLNode *temp) {
    int iBalance = diffAVL(temp);

    if (iBalance > 1) {
        if (diffAVL(temp->left) > 0) {
            temp = llRotation(temp);
        }
        else {
            temp = lrRotation(temp);
        }
    }
    else if (iBalance < -1) {
        if (diffAVL(temp->right) > 0) {
            temp = rlRotation(temp);
        }
        else {
            temp = rrRotation(temp);
        }

        return temp;
    }
}

AVL::AVLNode *AVL::insert(AVLNode *root, std::string insertion) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = new AVLNode;
        root->inputData = insertion;
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;

        //insertion is complete, escape function
        return root;
    }
    else if (insertion < root->inputData) {
        root->left = insert(root->left, insertion);
        root = balance(root);
    }
    else if (insertion >= root->inputData) {
        root->right = insert(root->right, insertion);
        root = balance(root);
    }

    return root;
}

void AVL::displayAVL(AVLNode *p, int l) {
    if (p != NULL) {
        displayAVL(p->right, l + 1);

        std::cout << std::endl;

        if (p == root) {
            std::cout << "Root > ";
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < l && p != root; i++) {
            std::cout << "     ";
        }

        std::cout << p->inputData;

        displayAVL(p->left, l + 1);
    }
}

AVL::AVL() {
    root = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried gdb and stepping into the problem?

Comment: @KRUKUSA I am not sure what gdb is. Care to enlighten me? :)

Comment: Sure it's hard to google. GDB is a program where you essentially can run your program line by line and print statements to see if your program is working as intended on a certain line. You can even step into functions to see if it's running through all your code properly.

Comment: I can promise you if you use GDB  and you know what you are doing, you can find out your exact issue on which line and from there it's an easy fix.

Comment: @KRUKUSA Is this possible to do with Windows? All the tutorials that I am searching for are Unix-specific. I am not running Unix. Is this the correct website? http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/download/

Comment: GDB can run on most popular UNIX and Microsoft Windows variants.

Comment: @KRUKUSA Thanks for the help. I will do my best to understand this and try to work it out. It seems like there are some hoops to jump through since I am using Visual Studio. :\ I should probably jump on the Unix bandwagon soon.

Comment: You have a misplaced `}` in your `balance` method. Fix that and I think things should work as expected. You should turn up the warning level on your compiler and listen to them. GCC 4.8.2 warns about your bug.

Comment: @Spikke Your `return` is in the wrong block. See my code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile with:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra  -g -I. *.cpp
```

Code:

```
// ----- avl.h -----
#include <string>

struct AVL {

  struct AVLNode {
    AVLNode* left;
    AVLNode* right;
    std::string inputData; };

  int heightAVL(AVLNode* temp);
  int diffAVL(AVLNode* temp);
  AVLNode* rrRotation(AVLNode* parent);
  AVLNode* llRotation(AVLNode* parent);
  AVLNode* lrRotation(AVLNode* parent);
  AVLNode* rlRotation(AVLNode* parent);
  AVLNode* balance(AVLNode* temp);
  AVLNode* insert(AVLNode* root, std::string insertion);
  void displayAVL(AVLNode* p, int l);
  AVL();

  AVLNode* root; };

// ----- avl.cpp -----
#include "avl.h"
#include <iostream>

int AVL::heightAVL(AVLNode* temp) {
  int iFinalHeight = 0;

  if (temp != NULL) {
    int lHeight = heightAVL(temp->left);
    int rHeight = heightAVL(temp->right);
    int topHeight = std::max(lHeight, rHeight);
    iFinalHeight = topHeight + 1; }

  return iFinalHeight; }


int AVL::diffAVL(AVLNode* temp) {
  int lHeight = heightAVL(temp->left);
  int rHeight = heightAVL(temp->right);
  int iBalance = lHeight - rHeight;
  return iBalance; }


AVL::AVLNode* AVL::rrRotation(AVLNode* parent) {
  AVLNode* temp;
  temp = parent->right;
  parent->right = temp->left;
  temp->left = parent;
  return temp; }


AVL::AVLNode* AVL::llRotation(AVLNode* parent) {
  AVLNode* temp;
  temp = parent->left;
  parent->left = temp->right;
  temp->right = parent;
  return temp; }


AVL::AVLNode* AVL::lrRotation(AVLNode* parent) {
  AVLNode* temp;
  temp = parent->left;
  parent->left = rrRotation(temp);
  return llRotation(parent); }


AVL::AVLNode* AVL::rlRotation(AVLNode* parent) {
  AVLNode* temp;
  temp = parent->right;
  parent->right = llRotation(temp);
  return rrRotation(parent); }


AVL::AVLNode* AVL::balance(AVLNode* temp) {
  int iBalance = diffAVL(temp);

  if (iBalance > 1) {
    if (diffAVL(temp->left) > 0) {
      temp = llRotation(temp); }
    else {
      temp = lrRotation(temp); } }
  else if (iBalance < -1) {
    if (diffAVL(temp->right) > 0) {
      temp = rlRotation(temp); }
    else {
      temp = rrRotation(temp); } }

  return temp; }


AVL::AVLNode* AVL::insert(AVLNode* root, std::string insertion) {
  if (root == NULL) {
    root = new AVLNode;
    root->inputData = insertion;
    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;
    return root; }
  else if (insertion < root->inputData) {
    root->left = insert(root->left, insertion); }
  else { /*if (insertion >= root->inputData)*/
    root->right = insert(root->right, insertion); }

  root = balance(root);
  return root; }


void AVL::displayAVL(AVLNode* p, int l) {
  if (p != NULL) {
    displayAVL(p->right, l + 1);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    if (p == root) {
      std::cout << "Root > "; }

    for (int i = 0; i < l && p != root; i++) {
      std::cout << "     "; }

    std::cout << p->inputData;
    displayAVL(p->left, l + 1); } }


AVL::AVL() {
  root = NULL; }

// ----- main.cpp -----
#include "avl.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

std::set<std::string> testData() {
  std::ifstream fin("avl.cpp");
  std::set<std::string> d;
  std::string v;

  while (fin >> v) {
    d.insert(v); }

  return d; }


int main() {
  AVL A;
  std::set<std::string> IndepSet = testData();

  for (std::set<std::string>::iterator it = IndepSet.begin();
       it != IndepSet.end(); it++) {
    A.root = A.insert(A.root, *it); }

  //3.    Display the top three levels of your AVL tree
  A.displayAVL(A.root, 3);
  return 0; }
```

Comment: Wow! That was REALLY hard to spot! My brain did NOT want to see that. Thank you so much!

Comment: That is why you want to turn on all the warnings from your compiler. The warning from GCC is: `warning: control reaches end of non-void function`. Which means, "this function does not always return something, but you said it would".

Comment: I guess that is not a default setting in Visual Studio? I know I've seen that warning before, and I do not recall changing any of the default warning settings.

Comment: I am less familiar with Studio's warnings and default settings.